# R create dataframe from data within xls file

Tags: r, dataframe, import-from-excel

I have an xls file that i am importing to R, i then want to create a dataframe of the table of data within the file, I'm currently getting stuck removing some of the data within the xls that i don't need.

In the below example I would like to create a data frame of cols A:G, excluding the 'xxxx' data.

```
xxxx    xxxxx                   
xxxx    xxxxx                   
xxxx    xxxxx                   
                        
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
2   3   4   5   6   7   8
3   4   5   6   7   8   9
4   5   6   7   8   9   10
5   6   7   8   9   10  11
6   7   8   9   10  11  12
7   8   9   10  11  12  13
8   9   10  11  12  13  14
9   10  11  12  13  14  15
                        
xxxxx
```

Comment: It would be best if you posted the result of `dput(yourdata)`.

Comment: while reading the data, use `skip` argument i.e. you may do `df1 <- read.csv('yourfile.csv', skip = 4)` i.e. the first 4 lines are not read

Comment: Thanks, how about to exclude any rows after the first blank in Col 1? I've got the data excl rows 1-4 so would now just need to exclude anything after the first blank (N/A) in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution, adding skip = 4 when importing the xls to exclude the first 4 rows and then this to exclude any rows after the first NA in col B:

```
NonNAindex <- which(!is.na(df$B))
firstNonNA <- max(NonNAindex)

df <- df[1:firstNonNA, ]
```